# Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('href=a"https:') is not a valid name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I was using the html-to-react parsing library, and initially, my code was working fine. But suddenly, it started giving this error. And as soon as I remove this function

```
<div className="w-3/4 ">
    <div
    key={idx}
    className="items-flex-start mt-5 h-full justify-end self-start rounded-[20px] bg-indigo-100 bg-cover p-[16px] text-start dark:text-gray-800"
    >
    {htmlToReactParser.parse(
        record.content.replaceAll(
        "<strong",
        '<strong style="cursor: pointer;"'
        )
    )}
    </div>
</div>
<div className="mt-24 flex w-1/4 justify-center">
    <div>
    <input
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(record)}
    />
    &nbsp; <strong>Download this part</strong>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

the code executes correctly.

My full code of the file is

```
  const HtmlToReact = require("html-to-react").Parser;
  
  const Solutions = ({
    error,
    problems,
    solution,
    success,
    problemId,
    changeProblem,
    getProblems,
    regenerateSolution,
    CreateParticularPdf,
    solutionLoading,
    createInteraction,
    createPdf,
  }: SolutionPayload) => {
    const htmlToReactParser = new HtmlToReact();
  
    // ..rest of mycode...
  
  
  
    
    return (
      <div className="mt-1">
  
        <Card
          extra={
            "items-flex-start w-full max-h-[32rem] min-h-48 p-[16px] bg-cover mt-10 overflow-y-scroll"
          }
        >
          {solution && solution.description ? (
            solution.description.map((record: SolutionContent, idx) =>
              record.role === "assistant" ? (
                <div className="mb-5 flex">
                  <div className="w-3/4 ">
                    <div
                      key={idx}
                      className="items-flex-start mt-5 h-full justify-end self-start rounded-[20px] bg-indigo-100 bg-cover p-[16px] text-start dark:text-gray-800"
                    >
                      {htmlToReactParser.parse(
                        record.content.replaceAll(
                          "<strong",
                          '<strong style="cursor: pointer;"'
                        )
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="mt-24 flex w-1/4 justify-center">
                    <div>
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(record)}
                      />
                      &nbsp; <strong>Download this part</strong>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ) : record.role === "user" &&
                !record.content.startsWith("Please provide an example of") ? (
                <div className="flex">
                  <div className="mt-10 flex w-1/4 justify-center">
                    <div>
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(record)}
                      />
                      &nbsp;<strong>Download this part</strong>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="w-3/4 ">
                    <div
                      key={idx}
                      className="items-flex-start mt-5 justify-end self-end rounded-[20px] bg-brand-100 bg-cover bg-cover p-[16px] p-[16px] text-start dark:text-gray-800"
                    >
                      {htmlToReactParser.parse(
                        record.content.replaceAll(
                          "<strong",
                          '<strong style="cursor: pointer;"'
                        )
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <></>
              )
            )
          ) : (
            <div className="mt-20 text-center">
              <h2 className="text-1xltracking-tight text-gray-400 sm:text-4xl">
                No Data
              </h2>
            </div>
          )}
        </Card>
      
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

I also try like import { Parser as HtmlToReactParser } from 'html-to-react'; but the error remain same.

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/hooks": "^2.1.4",
    "@chakra-ui/modal": "^2.2.9",
    "@chakra-ui/popover": "^2.1.8",
    "@chakra-ui/portal": "^2.0.15",
    "@chakra-ui/system": "^2.3.5",
    "@chakra-ui/tooltip": "^2.2.6",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@paypal/react-paypal-js": "^7.8.3",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.7.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.5",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "framer-motion": "^7.10.2",
    "html-react-parser": "^4.0.0",
    "html-to-react": "^1.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-calendar": "^3.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-share": "^4.4.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "serve": "^14.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.7.12",
    "sweetalert2-react-content": "^5.0.7",
    "tailwindcss-rtl": "^0.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "pretty": "prettier --write \"./**/*.{js,jsx,json}\""
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jspdf": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react-alert": "^7.0.2",
    "@types/react-calendar": "^3.5.2",
    "@types/react-modal": "^3.13.1",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.12",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
{
  "name": "jusaskin-sigma-saas-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/hooks": "^2.1.4",
    "@chakra-ui/modal": "^2.2.9",
    "@chakra-ui/popover": "^2.1.8",
    "@chakra-ui/portal": "^2.0.15",
    "@chakra-ui/system": "^2.3.5",
    "@chakra-ui/tooltip": "^2.2.6",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@paypal/react-paypal-js": "^7.8.3",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.7.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.5",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "framer-motion": "^7.10.2",
    "html-react-parser": "^4.0.0",
    "html-to-react": "^1.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-calendar": "^3.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-share": "^4.4.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "serve": "^14.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.7.12",
    "sweetalert2-react-content": "^5.0.7",
    "tailwindcss-rtl": "^0.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "pretty": "prettier --write \"./**/*.{js,jsx,json}\""
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jspdf": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react-alert": "^7.0.2",
    "@types/react-calendar": "^3.5.2",
    "@types/react-modal": "^3.13.1",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.12",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

record.content:

[image: record.content]

error:

[image: error]

If anyone knows the solution, please help me. I have been trying for the past 5 hours.

Comment: What does `record.content` look like? Is it valid HTML, and does it contain the odd-looking `'href=a"https:'` snippet that the error is warning about?

Comment: the record.content contain a valid html, i updated my question now please check @wander Nauta

Comment: Thanks for adding the `record.content` - though it seems to be cut off or incomplete. Can you add it as text instead of as an image?

Comment: Show a [mcve] please. Just enough HTML (one element, ideally) that still causes this to go wrong. Also: [dont show pictures of text](/help/how-to-ask), put the text in your post, as text.